# Wake on Lan doesn't work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wake-on-lan

I have a dual boot system with Windows 7 and Windows 8.

After I shutdown in Windows 7, wake-on-lan works perfect but if I shutdown in Windows 8, it doesn't work. Even if I sleep or hibernate in Windows 8, wake-on-lan works.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that it was related to the `Fast Startup` feature in Windows 8. After I disabled it, it worked fine.

Here is how:

1. Press the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.
2. Type `change power buttons` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   [image: S2]
3. Click `Change settings that are currently unavailable`.

   [image: S3]
4. Uncheck `Turn on fast startup`.

   [image: S4]
5. That's it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, Fast startup was already turned on.

Comment: Oh, what does fast startup do?

Comment: Hmm, sounds like something I'd like to keep. Is there any way to have my computer able to wake when I try to remote desktop, but still keep fast startup?

Comment: Sleep and hibernate will work even with fast startup enabled.

Comment: @Locutus Disabling fast startup has resolved my WOL issues just fine in Win 8.1 x64, so I'm afraid I have to disagree with you.

Comment: WOL still works after shutdown with hybrid shutdown enabled, **IF** you do shutdown "properly". Instead of using GUI (Windows Explorer or 3rd party Classic Shell makes no difference) and mouse-clicking, open command line and ussue standard `shutdown.exe /p /f` command (`/s` based command lines would work too, if you are curious - read the help and use options of your like) - and WOL will work. I can speculate, that the command line uses Windows Scheduler to shutdown the computer, or something else, which keeps ACPI power events enabled. Mere speculation though, i have no rational explanation.

Comment: I found this when testing VPN and Remote Desktop on Windows 8.1, the latter removed shutdown option from Start menu, so i had to use command line for turning computer off. And WOL worked like a charm. Next day i came back to office and wanted to show off - and it suddenly worked no more. And then i found this difference.

Answer (score 7):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2776718

> "As a result, Wake-On-LAN is only supported from sleep (S3) or hibernate (S4) in Windows 8."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229.aspx

> "Remote wake from hybrid shutdown (S4) or classic shutdown (S5) is
>   completely unsupported."

Answer (score 1):

You can wake up computers with Intel's AMT Power On (vPro) or AMD's DASH, even with quickboot enabled.  Just setting an admin password on a DASH enabled Broadcom card overrides Microsoft's command to turn off the NIC and traditional WOL starts to work again.

Intel's AMT will keep the NIC on if you set a password, but it didn't allow traditional WOL commands in our testing.  There are command line tools to wake a computer by AMT if you know its AMT password/IP address.

- Intel AMT
- Power on the vPro computer
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> before Windows starts to load
- Initial Admin password is "admin"
- Change the password to something else

Download the [Intel AMT Development Kit](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/download-the-latest-intel-amt-software-development-kit-sdk) 
Use the `remotecontrol.exe` tool to wake computers.

```
RemoteControl.exe -changepower on -host 192.168.1.5 -user admin -pass AMTpass
```

You can reset the password by unconfiguring the card in the main computer BIOS.

AMD DASH
Run the `setup.exe` that is contained in the driver download package for your computer's NIC (hopefully Broadcom).  This will install the Broadcom Advanced Control Suite (BACS).  This is required for other command line tools to configure the DASH chip.

Download the full Broadcom driver pack with utilities such as this one from HP.  It will contain the `BMCC.exe` utility for configuring the default password.
http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=7150467&swItemId=vc_147511_1&swEnvOid=4158

- `BMCC.exe edit`
- `u` (user accounts)
- `2` (accounts)
- `2.` administrator account
- `2` (enable account)
- `4.` try to change the password; doesn't work for me.
- `0,0,0,q` (quit and save)
- Access http://computername:623
- Logon as "Administrator" with no password (capital "A" required)
- Change the password there.

You can export the account change and import it using `BMCC.exe` as well. This assumes that the administrator account is the second entry of the 10 in the list.

```
BMCC export=c:\dash.txt -record:40:2
BMCC import=c:\dash.txt -record:40:2
```

To reset the password for a DASH client you have to reapply the firmware update.  This command came from the HP firmware update download for the Broadcom NIC.  The ORY file is the firmware.

```
WinFWUpg.exe restorenvram update\KC381FAC.ORY idmatch config
```

Comment: i wish intel vPro would have a standard WOL compatible option.  A setting that allows good old fashioned wake-on-lan packets to translate to whatever intel does to remote wake-up.  It is a crime that millions of PCs were shipped with the Energy Star logo, but wake-on-lan would not work and no one knew why for many years.

Comment: The newest hp models we have, Elite Desk 800 G3 seem to supercede this nonsense from MS and allow standard WOL again.  Perhaps some vendors are getting wise about what organizations want. 

I suppose it could be a security risk but only a minor one.  More of a power usage money sink.