# Ethernet port does not light up when computer is shut off in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, lan, power

I have a computer (desktop) that ran Windows 7 on it, until Friday, when I upgraded to Windows 8.

When my computer was turned off when I had Windows 7, the LAN lights on the Ethernet port were on. With Windows 8, I have lights; it's completely dark when my PC is off. Is this OK?

Comment: Define a lan light in this context?

Comment: Do you mean the LEDs on the network adapter or a router/modem that it is connected to?

Comment: Led on the network adapter where the LAN cable plugs into to rear of the computer

Answer (score 1):

Whether the ethernet LED stays on or off depends on your Operating System's and/or BIOS settings regarding [Wake on LAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN). If you have no interest in using this feature than you have not lost any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to do a hybrid shutdown (next time you startup your PC, a cold/slow boot would be done):

```
shutdown -s -t 0
```

Now, check if the LAN lights are on. If they are not, it is related to the incompatibility of Windows 8's fast startup feature with wake-on-lan. Check this [link](https://superuser.com/q/494965/112171) if you would like to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

This is for windows 10

1. Update network adapter driver
2. Right Click This PC > Manage > Device Manager > Network Adapters > Double Clicked on motherboard network adapter > Advanced tab > Enable **Shutdown Wake ON LAN**

Hopefully, it will be turned on now and you will be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's a bug in Window 7 and previous versions. Wake-on-LAN is only supposed to work from Hibernate and Sleep. Shutdown is supposed to completely power off everything including the NICs. Look for the artice on MSDN.

Comment: This kinda sucks. If you took the time to add an answer, at least add the actual link - that's what we are here for. I think this might be it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617165(v=ws.10).aspx